# Unrecognized sequence of bytes

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code:

```
.text:00537FDE                 push    offset a3Rrrrrrrrrrrrr ; "3L+ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐ+ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐøû9\n"
.text:00537FE3                 call    sub_5606A0
```

Where `offset a3Rrrrrrrrrrrrr` is:

```
.text:005379B0 a3Rrrrrrrrrrrrr db '3L+ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐ+ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐøû9',0Ah,0
```

The bytes from Hex View of this string:

```
.text:005379B0  33 C0 C3 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  3L+ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐ
.text:005379C0  C3 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  +ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐ
.text:005379D0  E8 EB 39 0A 00 68 C0 79  53 00 68 80 56 6A 00 6A  øû9.hLyS.hÀVj.j
```

And sub_5606A0:

```
.text:005606A0 sub_5606A0      proc near               ; CODE XREF: WinMain(x,x,x,x)+223p
.text:005606A0
.text:005606A0 arg_0           = dword ptr  4
.text:005606A0
.text:005606A0                 mov     eax, [esp+arg_0]
.text:005606A4                 mov     dword_8478CC, eax
.text:005606A9                 retn
.text:005606A9 sub_5606A0      endp
```

What can this encoded string mean?

```
.text:005379B0 a3Rrrrrrrrrrrrr db '3L+ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐ+ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐøû9',0Ah,0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that is not a string at all  notice  the first 3 bytes  33 c0 c3  that is epilog pop ebp, retn  it is the first argument to the call  which is saved to someplace and returned via eax  btw 0x90 (NOP opcode should not be shown as kind of D but as some kind of Latin A you may proabaly have a code page issue

Comment: Thanks! As turned out it is piece of assembler code.

Comment: @blabb looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @multithr3at3d  thanks for reminding i have converted it

Answer (score 3):

The Sequence of  Bytes do not represent a string

please take note of the first 3 bytes **0x33,0xc0,0xc3**

These are  opcodes for **xor eax,eax ,  retn**   basically **return 0; in c / c++**

```
0:000> eb . 33 c0 c3
0:000> u . l2
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
777a05a6 33c0            xor     eax,eax
777a05a8 c3              ret
0:000>
```

this is  probably a chunk of a function which has many return 0; statements

like
if(!a)retun 0; do b= blah(); if(!b) return0; .......

here the compiler might have recognized the repetition
and must have split the part into a seperate piece/chunk as part of optimization.

that said  0x90 aka NOP is shown as some kind of D

```
.text:005379B0  33 C0 C3 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  3L+ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐ
```

which indicates it is not probably a normal english locale encoding